# What is the uses of angular2 Polyfill js file

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Which configuration files are need to integrate angular2 application.

Answer (score 2):

All the required polyffils per browser and feature used are clearly listed in the Angular doc: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-support.html

Comment: Thank you! It really helps.